# Page layout structure with multiple asp.net chart controls in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have multiple chart dynamically created and attaching to pdf. Currently there are printing one on one line. I want to achieve something like this.
[image].
I want to create a container with some background and add columns like container in it.

```
 byte[] GetBarChartImage(params int[] points)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var chart = new Chart())
            {
                chart.Width = 200;
                chart.Height = 200;
                chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
                Series s = new Series();
                s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; ++i)
                {
                    s.Points.AddXY(points[i], points[i]);
                }
                chart.Series.Add(s);
                chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            }
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

and adding charts to pdf like this

```
pdfDoc.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(GetBarChartImage(3, 5, 7)));
pdfDoc.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(GetBarChartImage(2, 4, 6, 8)));
```

How to create this type of layout. Need help